# How can I hide the vent pipe for my septic system?

Tags: drain-waste-vent, sewer

I'm in the process of buying a newly built house and today the builder had work done on the sewer. When I saw the house I couldn't believe that they placed the 3-4" high 'Candy Cane' smack dab in the middle of the front yard. This completely ruins the appearance of the house and I just don't know what to do about it.

If I cover it up with a bush, fake wishing well, or something of that nature then it won't look right since it's in the middle/center of the front yard. If it were off to the side then I think that would potentially work but it's not.

The only thing I can think of is repiping it somewhere else or maybe cutting it down myself (regardless of what any regulations say). If I cut it down and it snows I'll just shovel around it. Is this a big job for a plumber or someone to come out and repipe it to a more discrete location? I'm wondering if I should complain to the builder and have him fix it before it's completely my responsibility.

Here is a picture of it, however I should have taken it at a different angle so you could see my house and the pipe in comparison (the picture only shows my neighbors house).

[image]

Comment: For Christmas season you could put out a dozen more and spirl wrap each one with a red ribbon.

Comment: If it's a deal breaker, start looking for your out in the contract, any contingency like agreeing to HOA paperwork can be used as your escape. And let the builder know this is a deal breaker and they're going to lose the sale, they may be able to move it, possibly out of your yard entirely.

Comment: What you have there is an opportunity. Try a trellis with a clematis growing on it, some bamboo, a Japanese yew, or just a plain old high bush cranberry.

Comment: I assume that pipe on the left is your well-head for your drinking water? I shudder thinking about how close that septic tank is to your well head. Best hope it never leaks...

Comment: I would put rocks around it with plants

Comment: Looks like well access pipe is just a few feet away from a sewer vent (presumably above a drain field).  Looks like you've got bigger problems than hiding the sewer vent.  Unless that's your neighbors well, then you're good :)

Answer (score 5):

Cutting it off is a bad idea. Aborting the "process of buying" that you're in might be worth considering if it bothers you that much. Relocating it significantly would probably require significantly relocating the septic system, which is very expensive - so you might consider it a "deal-breaker."

As for the location in the center of the yard, simply change your mindset from "I'm hiding this ugly thing I cannot believe is here" to "I'm putting a centerpiece in my lawn/yard."

I'd go for a planting, myself, but seriously get out of the mindset (while retaining the function) of "just hide the darn thing" - put in a carefully laid out bed that has some shrubs that happen to hide it (paint it in camouflage colors, as well - white pipe does stand out.)

Answer (score 3):

If you were to cut this down, it may not only be bad for yourself, but your neighbors that are on the same sewer system (assuming this isn't for a septic tank).

Your options include landscaping (plantings in the middle of the yard are common, particularly with a focal tree or flower bed), fake rocks, concealing inside of a bird bath or sundial stand, concealing inside of a fake stone column, converting it to a mushroom style cap that looks more like landscape lighting, and painting it to blend in  to the landscaping.

Answer (score 2):

It may be permissible to replace the candy cane vent with a mushroom style cap allowing you to cut the pipe a little lower to the ground making it more inconspicuous.  I've noticed there are products on the market that add a carbon filter below the mushroom cap to absorb odors in the event your sewer pipe stinks.

Answer (score 1):

In my area, I've seen some people use decorative wishing wells to conceal pipes like this. It actually looks pretty good.

Example:

[image]